# Navigation titleView not showing in ContentPage

Tags: css, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

New to Xamarin and I was trying to create a custom navigation bar in my Cross-Platform App. I needed to hide navigation titleView in one of the three content pages.

```
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"
```

Also i have used a bottom toolbar
`android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"` at MainPages.xaml.
When i try to add title at the two other tabs, there are no changes on the top bar but it appears as title of bottom tab referred to each content page.
I have tried the code above in xaml related to the right content page

```
<ContentPage ... Title="Test"...>...</ContentPage
```

and also on cs as the codes above:

I. About.cs

```
Title = "Test";
```

II. MainPages.cs

```
itemsPage = new About()
                    {
                        Title = "Test"
                    };
```

**I'm also adding the pic related to the situation**

**>>>** [Top NavigationBar is blank, the changes are applied to the bottomBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRSKR.png)

When I try to make custom change with Navigation.TitleView as below:

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>       
     <Label Text="Tests" TextColor="Black"/>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

...even if i set `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="true"`, anyways it doesn't work. The results is nothing in the top and bottom bar.

**I'm also adding the pic related to the situation**

**>>>**[No changes applied at Top or Bottom bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scAwz.png)

I'm not sure if I have mistaken any step while i was hiden NavigationBar in the first tab. I made instant changes in styles.xml too, which i think not, anyways here's a passage below:

```
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Comment: What is your MainPage in your `App.xaml.cs`? Are you using a NavigationPage?

Comment: MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPages(status)); @JuanSturla

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ToolbarItems`:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Title" Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
        <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="img" Order="Primary" Priority="1" />
        <ToolbarItem Text="Something" Order="Primary" Priority="2" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: These are toolbar items, my problem is with the title's content pages of the three main navigations.